# Why am I getting unrecognized selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I run my app which loads images in table view from a parse server. I updated the code and now this is my error:
**-[UIImageView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156b6890**

I can usually fix my problems eventually but
I have no idea how to even start trying to fix this please help.

Here is my .m:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == self.objects.count) {
    return nil;
}
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeaderCell";
PFTableViewCell *sectionHeaderView = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //  PFImageView *profileImageView = (PFImageView *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *userNameLabel = (UILabel *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:3];

PFObject *photo = [self.objects objectAtIndex:section];

PFUser *user = [photo objectForKey:@"whoPosted"];
// PFFile *profilePicture = [user objectForKey:@"ProfilePicture"];
NSString *title = photo[@"title"];


userNameLabel.text = user.username;
titleLabel.text = title;



//profileImageView.file = profilePicture;
//[profileImageView loadInBackground];


//follow button
FollowButton *followButton = (FollowButton *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:4];
followButton.delegate = self;
followButton.sectionIndex = section;

if (!self.followingArray || [user.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId])       {
    followButton.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    followButton.hidden = NO;
    NSInteger indexOfMatchedObject = [self.followingArray indexOfObject:user.objectId];
    if (indexOfMatchedObject == NSNotFound) {
        followButton.selected = NO;
    }
    else {
        followButton.selected = YES;
    }
  }

   return sectionHeaderView;
   }
```

When I run the app right now it loads one image with no information with it and it just says loading and never loads anything else. My app should at least load 5 images and some text at least is use to. Im not real sure what I changed created this. Thanks.

My follow button in storyboard has a class of FollowButton here is the .m:
    #import "FollowButton.h"

```
@implementation FollowButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
if (self == [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
return self;
}


- (void) buttonPressed {
[self.delegate followButton:self didTapWithSelectionIndex:self.sectionIndex];

}


@end
```

Comment: It appears that the section header view is actually a `UIImageView` and not a `FollowButton`.

Comment: BTW - narrow the code in your question down to just the relevant portions related to the crash.

Comment: "Unrecognized selector" means that you're trying to call a method or access a property on an object that doesn't have such a method/property. Often it's because you think an object is of a certain type when it's really something else. For example, you can't call `String` methods on an `Int`, and you can't call `setDelegate` on an object that doesn't have a `delegate` property to set, which is your current problem. Looks like you're mixing up `FollowButton` with UIImageView, which doesn't have a delegate.

Comment: @Caler Use the debugger. See where the app crashes. See why the header view subview is a `UIImageView` instead of the expected `FollowButton`.

Comment: @Caler - You're currently saying followButton HAS a delegate, not that it IS one, and that you want its delegate to be the current viewController, `self`. What was your reason for this (handing off responsibility for some function to the current vc)? The error is telling you that what you think is a FollowButton with a delegate property apparently isn't - it's a UIImageView instead. Maybe the tag is wrong? Or its class isn't set properly in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

As you've been told in the comments, the problem is these two lines:

```
FollowButton *followButton = (FollowButton *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:4];
followButton.delegate = self;
```

The problem is that your `viewWithTag:4` turns out to be a UIImageView - and UIImageViews don't have delegates. Evidently you're fetching the wrong view here. Check your tag numbering!

---

Further comments:

- You can *say* it's a FollowButton (and your code does say so) but that doesn't mean it is one. It is what it is — what it *really* is. In other words, when you cast this thing to a FollowButton, you are accidentally lying.
- The reason the error message mentions `setDelegate:` is that setting something's `delegate` property is identical to calling its `setDelegate:` method.

Hope that info helps you track down this same sort of error in future, as you'll be seeing it a lot. I'd guess that "unrecognized selector" is the single most common runtime error. Learn to love it (and to fix it).

Comment: My tag 4 is a UIButton tho @matt :( thats why I am so confused. I just checked to make sure that the tags were correct.

Comment: @Caler try the code snippet in my answer below, set a breakpoint on the second line, and inspect view4... there's clearly a case where it is something that does not allow a delegate, a UIImageView as the error message states.

Comment: @Caler Believe the runtime. It knows more than you do.

Comment: @Caler Also a UIButton has no delegate either.

Comment: The way I have it is the button has a class of FollowButton. I will post that class in my answer. @matt

Comment: @Caler And I'm telling you that it isn't. Well, not me; the runtime. It's easy to go wrong here. Suppose you mistakenly have _two_ views with tag 4; how do you know which one will get picked? Maybe your FollowButton has tag 4, but there is also a UIImageView in your interface that _also_ has tag 4. There _must_ be. Believe the runtime! Do not squirm and fight back - debug!

Answer (score 0):

Consider these lines of your code:

```
PFTableViewCell *sectionHeaderView = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
...
FollowButton *followButton = (FollowButton *)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:4];
followButton.delegate = self;
```

The cast to `(FollowButton *)` is unsafe! At the least, check it:

```
UIView *view4 = [sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:4];
if([view4 isKindOfClass:[FollowButton class]]) {
    FollowButton *followButton = (FollowButton *) view4;
    followButton.delegate = self;
} else {
    NSLog(@"I got the wrong view: %@", view4);
}
```

In tens of thousands of lines of iOS code I have written, I amazed how rarely it is correct to do a typecast. They are the source of many bugs and if you don't have a method to get things back of correct type, it's a possible warning sign. And ALWAYS check your typecasts because otherwise the runtime errors are difficult to diagnose...

Comment: "how rarely it is correct to do a typecast" Unfortunately that's just not true. Methods often return `id` or some general type higher than something's real type (UIViewController, UIView, etc.). You have no choice but to cast down to the real type in order to get correct compiler type-checking.

Comment: @Caler are you saying that it also did not crash?

Comment: @matt what methods return `id`? Very view in Apple's frameworks do. And if you use (instancetype) correctly, very few of your own should as well. I'm interested in your examples.

Comment: Well I ran the check and the NSlog does not get called and the app doesn't crash if thats what you mean. @RobP

Comment: @RobP A _lot_ of them do. Perhaps you just haven't noticed because you cast as soon as you receive one. For example, every array is effectively an array of `id`. Every time you fetch an element of an NSArray, you get an `id`. Thus every method that returns an array has removed the typing from the array's contents. `myView.subviews[0]` is an `id`. You probably cast / assign it immediately to a UIView so you don't notice this. But this is an excellent place for things to go wrong in real life...

Comment: @matt Most of the time, you shouldn't access the array directly and typecast. You call a method exposed by the owner of the array which returns a typed object, and the owner can typecast safely because they control what gets added to the array.